# Visa to France refused twice for a 2-year old baby

Tags: visa, indian-citizens

I have an Indian friend whose wife(Student Visa) is coming to do her management studies in France. They have a two year-old daughter.

Now the problem is that the daughter's visa has been refused two times, i.e. when they applied for her visa, it was refused (for the first time, not tourism) and then they tried for a tourism visa (didn't work either, second time refused).

I wanted to help them but I have no idea how. Is there a way to get the baby with her mother? Who can we contact in this regard? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the wife's visa type? What were the grounds for the first refusal? (The second application was probably refused because a baby accompanying a student is definitely not a tourist.)

Comment: You asked the identical question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101673/visa-to-france-got-cancelled-twice-for-a-2yrs-old-baby) and it was put on hold for being too broad.

Comment: Without detailed knowledge about the case (especially scans of the refusal notices) this question is too broad and/or unclear. Therefore I am voting to close until you edit.

Comment: @Shamina, if you can update this with the details of the first refusal, it would allow somebody to perhaps provide some advice.

Comment: You still have not updated us with the details of the child's first refusal. We need to know what kind of visa, and the exact reasons given for the first refusal. It wouldn't hurt to give details about the second refusal  as well, although that is quite obvious.